# Access to Serial Port in the second form in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am developing an app in Visual Studio using C# that communicates with a data acquisition device. The first form connects to the available com port and sends the device password. After that, I have access to the device setting called configuration. Clicking on the Configuration button opens up a second form and gives 11 options corresponding to different device settings. Everything works well in the first form.
Here are my codes for Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Configuration; //Serial port handling


namespace Developing_Serial_Terminal_for_Arduino_in_C_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort SerPort;    //Creating the serial port we want to connect to
        private string ReceivedData;   //Creating a variable to receive the data

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FetchAvailablePorts();
        }
        void FetchAvailablePorts()
        {
            String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames(); //We get the available COM ports
            AvailablePortsBox.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void ConnectToPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerPort = new SerialPort();

            SerPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            SerPort.PortName = AvailablePortsBox.Text;
            SerPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            SerPort.DataBits = 8;
            SerPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            SerPort.ReadBufferSize = 20000000;
            SerPort.DataReceived += SerPort_DataReceived;

            try
            {
                SerPort.Open();
                lblStatusCom.Text = "ON";
                lblStatusCom.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error! Try again!");
            }
        }
        private void DisconnectFromPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SerPort.IsOpen)
            {
                SerPort.Close();
                lblStatusCom.Text = "OFF";
                lblStatusCom.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void SerPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReceivedData = SerPort.ReadLine(); //read the line from the serial port

            this.Invoke(new Action(ProcessingData));
        }

        private void ProcessingData()
        {
            ReceivedDataBox.Text += ReceivedData.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void SendSerialButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SerPort.WriteLine(SendertextBox.Text.ToString());
            SerPort.WriteLine("");
            Thread.Sleep(4000); //sleep for 4 seconds
            SerPort.WriteLine("Device password");
            Thread.Sleep(4000); //sleep for 4 seconds
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                DialogResult dr =MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit the App?", "Exit Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Application.ExitThread();
                }
                else { }
            }
        }

        private void btnConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerPort.WriteLine("config");
            var newform = new Configuration();
            newform.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, in the second form, when I try to send "1" to the device that corresponds to the 1st option of the configuration menu, I don't know how to do that. SerPort.WriteLine("1") is for choosing the option 1 from the config list!
Here are my codes for the second form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration; //Serial port handling

namespace Developing_Serial_Terminal_for_Arduino_in_C_
{
    public partial class Configuration : Form
    {
        //private SerialPort SerPort;    //Creating the serial port we want to connect to
        //private string ReceivedData;   //Creating a variable to receive the data
        public Configuration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnGenDeviceConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SerPort.WriteLine("1");
            var newform = new GenDeviceConfig();
            newform.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit the Config page?", "Exit Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
                else { }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `new Configuration()` you could give the new form a reference to the serial port, withe by a constructor argument (preferred), or by setting `newform.SerPort = SerPort;` (requiring Configuration.SerPort to be public).

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Comment: `public static SerialPort SerPort;`, now you can simply use Form1.SerPort anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `SerialPort` that has been opened in `Form1` from the `Configuration` form, you have to pass it to the new form somehow.

**Option 1: via the constructor**

Change `public Configuration()` to `public Configuration(SerialPort serPort)` and in the constructor body, assign `SerPort = serPort;`.

When creating the second form, pass the serial port as `new Configuration(SerPort);`

**Option 2: by a public property**

Make `Configuration.SerPort` a public property: `public SerialPort SerPort { get; set;}`. Then you can assign it after you created `var newform = new Configuration();` by `newForm.SerPort = SerPort;`

Comment: What if there are multiple forms of the same thing?

Comment: At the same time? Wouldn't they interfere with each other?

Comment: There is a setting option 1 to 10 and each number opens a new set of options and there is an exit for each list which should tame me back to the previous form. it worked for the second form, but the third form is not working! Kind of hierarchical.

Comment: Well, you could pass the SerialPort object along any levels of forms. Or as Hans suggested in his comment, just use a static field in one central place.